# Python loop performance

Tags: python-3.x, for-loop

If I loop through 1 big list like:

```
range1 = list(range(100))

for i in range1:
    print ('i')
```

Will it be faster than looping through a nested list with the same number of iterables:

```
range2 = list(range(10))
range3 = list(range(10))

for i in range2:
    for ii in range3:
        print ('i')
```

I'm guessing it will be the same, but I'm not sure if iterable number (correct word?) is the only determinant of loop performance.  Thought I would check with the coding gods!

Cheers,
Tim

Comment: It strongly depends on what you will do with that loop data. If you just print it, it shouldn't matter but I suppose that's not what you plan. It also depends on data sizes in relation to cache sizes. If you repeatedly loop a list and it fits the CPU cache completely you won't have cache misses and you don't need to load as much data. So second version has the tendency to be faster. Also you tagged the question as 3.x but used `print` as a statement which is Python 2.x behavior, so what version are you referring to?

Comment: Thanks for your reply!  I don't have a plan in particular, I was just rewriting some code to remove nested for loops in an attempt to make my script quicker, and wondered if nested for-loops were always worse (performance wise) compared to flat for-loops - this is the impression I have got so far!  In terms of print, I thought python 3 just included it in brackets - I didn't know it had any other changes.  I have edited some errors in my original question, maybe i forgot the brackets in the first version.  Apologies, I might have confused things :P

Comment: If you have a nested loop it really depends on the nature of that nesting. In the example you gave, you just repeatedly loop over the same data `range3` again and again. So in case that doesn't exceed your CPU's cache size it will be significantly faster than the flat version which needs to load power of 2 as much data into the cache as the nested version. Taking the numbers from your example, the flat version needs to load `100` elements into cache while the nested version only loads `20`.

Comment: Ahhh I think I get you - thanks for the explanation it's clear now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is the same thing because of something called "Time Complexity". This is how much the time scales with the given input. It's hard to explain in just a post like this, but it means that you're looping through 100 elements no matter what and it won't change the duration.
I recommend this video where it is explained perfectly: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=D6xkbGLQesk

Comment: Ahhh this is great, thank you for the video I will give it a watch!

Comment: I'd appreciate a tick, since I'm new in this website and trying to build my reputation!